# Is there any FaceTime API for iPhone developers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facetime

I am developing an application having FaceTime feature. How do I know when both are connected/disconnected using FaceTime? I need to restrict the call duration and also I don't want to show others FaceTime ID when it is getting connected because of security reasons. Is there any delegate to know those details? Could anyone give some idea to get it?

Answer (score 10):

There is no FaceTime api in the offical API.

You can use the the facetime url scheme:

> facetime://

Comment: Thanks for the response,I agree with you. Is there any alternative to get the video call instead of facetime like thrid party sdks, since facetime doesnot have an API.

Comment: No there isn't any available API for facetime in iOS 5 SDk

Comment: Can you call specific users with the url scheme?

Comment: The FaceTime URL scheme is also undocumented and therefore considered private by Apple. Your app will be rejected when using the FaceTime URL scheme.

Comment: @pre It is not the case as of now.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html