# Are there any iPhone plugins for video conferencing? Like a face-time plugin?

Tags: iphone, facetime, video-conferencing

i'm trying to do some R&D with my iPhone and want to have a 'page' that can do facetime or some video conf thing.

I know this has been [asked before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631921/is-there-any-facetime-api-for-iphone-developers) .. but i'm not sure if that's the same question or applicable answer for me.

Bascially, i want to start a vid conf with another person - in my app .. but leverage existing infrastructure. If it's a paid service - then fine. I'm just R&D'ing stuff right now.

Can anyone suggest any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SkypeKit](http://developer.skype.com/signup) is currently in closed beta, but there is a waiting list.

Comment: Kewl :) I'm sure there will be more stuff (eg HTML5 Streaming API - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#stream-api) that will slowly make it's way into the iPhone in time .. but for the time of this post - that sounds like a plausible solution.